# How to create a universal program code for different versions of a program library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, libraries

I use a software library that has different function names in different versions of the library.

I try to use the following code:

```
some_variable = module.old_name_of_function()
```

But this code only works with the old version of the program library.

I plan to use the code on different computers, with different installed versions of the software library.

Some computers have a new version of the program library installed, and the following code should be used there:

```
some_variable = module.new_name_of_function()
```

And if I use `old_name_of_function()` in the new version of the library, I will get an error.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you get more specific on the library, the versions, the systems and the changes? There might be an easy solution like virtual environments or pinned dependencies.

Comment: To  Klaus D.: I use Rpy2 library: 1) version 2.9 in Ubuntu and Debian forks. 2) version 3.0.3 in Ubuntu fork. Code for 2.9 version: `with localconverter(ro.default_converter + pandas2ri.converter):
  some_dataframe = ro.conversion.ri2py(r_dataframe)`, and for 3.0.3 version: `with localconverter(ro.default_converter + pandas2ri.converter):
  some_dataframe = ro.conversion.rpy2py(r_dataframe)`. Documentation: https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.0.x/html/generated_rst/pandas.html

Comment: Differences: `.ri2py` and `.rpy2py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could do

```
try:
    my_func = module.old_name_of_function
except AttributeError:
    my_func = module.new_name_of_function

some_variable = my_func()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pkg_resources` module for it (example for numpy):

```
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.get_distribution("numpy").version
```

will return:

`'1.15.2'`

Then you can use `case`s, `if`s or something else to run a function you need.

For example:

```
import pkg_resources
version = pkg_resources.get_distribution("numpy").version
v = version.split('.')

if int(v[0]) == 1 and int(v[1]) < 17:
    print('WAKA')
else:
    print('NEW WAKA')
```

will print 'WAKA' for every 1.X version of `numpy`, where X < 17.